# TSQL, how to update first avail bucket ONLY,

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to do this update to add another value to a series of buckets (B1-B5), but only 1 time into first available, like in sample below, can not come up with any solution to mark it once it filled, tried to use flag, but looks like it doesn't' work during the same tx.  This is sample code which is not right yet. I'm on MSQL 2016.
Thanks all for review;

```
/*
SELECT * INTO #t FROM (
SELECT 101 CustID, 100 B1, 200 B2 , NULL B3, NULL B4, NULL B5, '0' [f], 111 NewB , 'B4,B5 sbe empty' Note UNION
SELECT 102 CustID, 100 B1, 200 B2 , 300 B3, NULL B4,  NULL B5, '0' [f], 222 NewB , '22 goes only into B4, B5 empty' Note   UNION
SELECT 103 CustID, 100 B1, 200 B2 , 300 B3, 400  B4 , NULL B5, '0' [f], 333 NewB , '333 goes into B5' Note    )x                       */
--     SELECT * FROM #t              -- before                  DROP TABLE #t


-- how to Put  NewB only ONCE into first empty B1-5
update #t 
SET B1 = CASE WHEN B1 IS NULL THEN NewB ELSE B1 END,   
    B2 = CASE WHEN B2 IS NULL THEN NewB ELSE B2 END,
    B3 = CASE WHEN B3 IS NULL THEN NewB ELSE B3 END,
    B4 = CASE WHEN B4 IS NULL THEN NewB ELSE B4 END,
    B5 = CASE WHEN B5 IS NULL THEN NewB ELSE B5 END 

    SELECT * FROM #t
----------------------

CustID  B1   B2  B3  B4  B5 _   NewB    Note
101    100  200 111 111 111 -   111     B4,B5 sbe empty
102    100  200 300 222 222 -   222     B5 sbe empty
103    100  200 300 400 333 -   333     333 goes into B5

**  tried :   f = CASE WHEN B1 IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   ,
A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause
```

Comment: Why are you storing values in columns that should be in separate rows?

Answer (score 1):

Test whether all previous ones are not null, i.e. have not been set.

```
update #t
SET B1 = CASE WHEN B1 IS NULL THEN NewB ELSE B1 END,   
    B2 = CASE WHEN B2 IS NULL AND
        B1 IS NOT NULL THEN NewB ELSE B2 END,
    B3 = CASE WHEN B3 IS NULL AND
        B1 IS NOT NULL AND B2 IS NOT NULL THEN NewB ELSE B3 END,
    B4 = CASE WHEN B4 IS NULL AND
        B1 IS NOT NULL AND B2 IS NOT NULL AND B3 IS NOT NULL THEN NewB ELSE B4 END,
    B5 = CASE WHEN B5 IS NULL AND 
           B1 IS NOT NULL AND B2 IS NOT NULL AND B3 IS NOT NULL AND B4 IS NOT NULL
         THEN NewB ELSE B5 END
    SELECT * FROM #t
```

See also: [Importance of Column Order in the SET Clause in Update Statements](http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server/Importance_of_Column_Order_in_SET_Clause.html)

Comment: Mercy Olivier!!

Answer (score 1):

You should check the values of all the preceding columns:

```
update #t 
SET B1 = CASE WHEN B1 IS NULL THEN NewB ELSE B1 END,   
    B2 = CASE WHEN B1 IS NULL AND B2 IS NULL THEN NewB ELSE B2 END,
    B3 = CASE WHEN B1 IS NULL AND B2 IS NULL AND B3 IS NULL THEN NewB ELSE B3 END,
    B4 = CASE WHEN B1 IS NULL AND B2 IS NULL AND B3 IS NULL AND B4 IS NULL THEN NewB ELSE B4 END,
    B5 = CASE WHEN B1 IS NULL AND B2 IS NULL AND B3 IS NULL AND B4 IS NULL AND B5 IS NULL THEN NewB ELSE B5 END
```

Alternatively, you can use separate update statements, but remove the value of NewB in the first UPDATE that affects the row:

```
ALTER TABLE #t ALTER COLUMN NewB INT NULL

update #t SET B1 = NewB, NewB=NULL WHERE B1 IS NULL AND NewB IS NOT NULL
update #t SET B2 = NewB, NewB=NULL WHERE B2 IS NULL AND NewB IS NOT NULL
update #t SET B3 = NewB, NewB=NULL WHERE B3 IS NULL AND NewB IS NOT NULL
update #t SET B4 = NewB, NewB=NULL WHERE B4 IS NULL AND NewB IS NOT NULL
update #t SET B5 = NewB, NewB=NULL WHERE B5 IS NULL AND NewB IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a reference field using `CROSS APPLY` that indicates which column should be updated. In the code below, `IIF` can be replaced with a `CASE` expression if desired.

```
UPDATE t
SET B1 = IIF(NextBucket = 'B1', NewB, B1)
  , B2 = IIF(NextBucket = 'B2', NewB, B2)
  , B3 = IIF(NextBucket = 'B3', NewB, B3)
  , B4 = IIF(NextBucket = 'B4', NewB, B4)
  , B5 = IIF(NextBucket = 'B5', NewB, B5)
FROM #t t
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT NextBucket = CASE
                                          WHEN B1 IS NULL THEN 'B1'
                                          WHEN B2 IS NULL THEN 'B2'
                                          WHEN B3 IS NULL THEN 'B3'
                                          WHEN B4 IS NULL THEN 'B4'
                                          WHEN B5 IS NULL THEN 'B5'
                                        END) nb;
```

Comment: Tx much Razvan, KC & Steven.

Answer (score 1):

```
update #t
SET 
b1 = coalesce( b1, newb),
b2 = case when b1 is not null then coalesce(b2, newb) else b2 end,
b3 = case when b1 is not null and b2 is not null then  coalesce(b3, newb)  else b3 end,
b4 = case when b1 is not null and b2 is not null and b3 is not null then coalesce(b4, newb) else b4 end,
b5 = case when b1 is not null and b2 is not null and b3 is not null and b4 is not null then coalesce(b5, newb) else b5 end
```